# Building a set of records incrementally as app progresses

Tags: python, data-structures

I have an sysadmin type CLI app that reads in info from a config file. I cannot change the format of the config file below.

```
TYPE_A = "value1,value2,value2"
TYPE_A = "value3,value4,value5"
TYPE_B = "valuex,valuey,valuez"
```

Based on the `TYPE`, I'll need to do some initial processing with each one. After I'm done with that step for all, I need to do some additional processing and depending on the options chosen either print the state and intended action(s) or execute those action(s).

I'd like to do the initial parsing of the config into a dict of lists of dicts and update every instance of `TYPE_A`, `TYPE_B`, `TYPE_C`, etc with all the pertinent info about it. Then either print the full state or execute the actions (or fail if the state of something was incorrect)

My thought is it would look something like:

```
dict
    TYPE_A_list
        dict_A[0] key:value,key:value,key:value
        dict_A[1] key:value,key:value,key:value
    TYPE_B_list
        dict_A[0] key:value,key:value,key:value
        dict_A[1] key:value,key:value,key:value
```

I think I'd want to read the config into that and then add keys and values or update values as the app progresses and reprocesses each TYPE.

Finally my questions.

1. I'm not sure how iterate over each list of dicts or to add list elements and add or update key:value pairs.
2. Is what I describe above the best way to go about this?

I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm open to any advice. FWIW, this will be python 2.6.

A little clarification on the config file lines

```
    CAR_TYPE = "Ford,Mustang,Blue,2005"
    CAR_TYPE = "Honda,Accord,Green,2009"
    BIKE_TYPE = "Honda,VTX,Black,2006"
    BIKE_TYPE = "Harley,Sportster,Red,2010"
    TIRE_TYPE = "170R15,whitewall"
```

Each type will have the same order and number of values.

Answer (score 0):

No need to "remember" there are two different `TYPE_A` assignments - you can combine them.

```
TYPE_A = "value1,value2,value2"
TYPE_A = "value3,value4,value5"
```

would be parsed as only one of them, or both, depends on the implementation of your sysadmin CLI app.

Then the data model should be:

```
dict
    TYPE_A: list(value1, value2, value3)
    TYPE_B: list(valuex, valuey, valuez)
```

That way, you can iterate through `dict.items()` pretty easily:

```
for _type, values in dict.items():
    for value in values:
        print "%s: %s" % (_type, value)
        # or whatever you wish to do
```

Comment: I need to have them separate. Like the clarification above, I think of each line as a single set of values of TYPE. "TYPE,value,value,value"